# Reduce ImageSpan height and width

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spannablestring, imagespan

I'm setting an Image Drawable as a SpannableString to a TextView but the image comes out larger than the text making it look weird. I need to reduce the size of the imagespan such that it's the same height as the text:

Here's what I've tried:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(holder.temptext.getText());
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable), selectionCursor - ":)".length(), selectionCursor, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.temptext.setText(builder);
holder.temptext.setSelection(selectionCursor);

holder.caption.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to measure your `TextView`'s height and use it instead of intrinsic bounds:

```
int lineHeight = holder.temptext.getLineHeight();

drawable.setBounds(0, 0, lineHeight, lineHeight);
```

Comment: this doesn't maintain the image's aspect ratio

Comment: You can calculate the new width like this `val width =  lineHeight * drawable.intrinsicWidth / drawable.intrinsicHeight`.